# How can I get an array to read user input then output according to specific number?

Tags: c

So right now the program outputs from MAX to MIN correctly however the Number of responses is wrong. It seems as if it outputs only the last correct consecutively placed responses. The code is last.

What it does:

```
Enter a integer rating between -20 and 5 for the product: 5
Enter a integer rating between -20 and 5 for the product: 4
Enter a integer rating between -20 and 5 for the product: 3
Enter a integer rating between -20 and 5 for the product: 2
Enter a integer rating between -20 and 5 for the product: 3
Enter a integer rating between -20 and 5 for the product: 1

Rating            Number of Responses
------            -------------------
  5                       1
  4                       1
  3                       1
  2                       1
  1                       1
  0                       1
 -1                       1
 -2                       1
 -3                       1
 -4                       1
 -5                       1
 -6                       1
 -7                       1
 -8                       1
 -9                       1
-10                       1
-11                       1
-12                       1
-13                       1
-14                       1
-15                       1
-16                       1
-17                       1
-18                       1
-19                       1
-20                       1
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 13.643 s
Press any key to continue.
```

What it should do:

```
Enter a integer rating between -20 and 5 for the product: 5
Enter a integer rating between -20 and 5 for the product: 4
Enter a integer rating between -20 and 5 for the product: 3
Enter a integer rating between -20 and 5 for the product: 2
Enter a integer rating between -20 and 5 for the product: 3
Enter a integer rating between -20 and 5 for the product: 1

Rating            Number of Responses
------            -------------------
  5                       1
  4                       1
  3                       2
  2                       1
  1                       1
  0                       0
 -1                       0
 -2                       0
 -3                       0
 -4                       0
 -5                       0
 -6                       0
 -7                       0
 -8                       0
 -9                       0
-10                       0
-11                       0
-12                       0
-13                       0
-14                       0
-15                       0
-16                       0
-17                       0
-18                       0
-19                       0
-20                       0
Process returned 0 (0x0)  execution time : 13.643 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Another Example(Working Incorrectly):

```
Enter a integer rating between -20 and 5 for the product: 5
Enter a integer rating between -20 and 5 for the product: 4
Enter a integer rating between -20 and 5 for the product: 22

Not within range. Try again.
You have 3 more attempts before program outputs total:2

Enter a integer rating between -20 and 5 for the product: 2
Enter a integer rating between -20 and 5 for the product: 2
Enter a integer rating between -20 and 5 for the product: 2

Rating            Number of Responses
------            -------------------
  5                       3
  4                       3
  3                       3
  2                       3
  1                       3
  0                       3
 -1                       3
 -2                       3
 -3                       3
 -4                       3
 -5                       3
 -6                       3
 -7                       3
 -8                       3
 -9                       3
-10                       3
-11                       3
-12                       3
-13                       3
-14                       3
-15                       3
-16                       3
-17                       3
-18                       3
-19                       3
-20                       3
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 8.426 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Here it is...

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                             /* Necessary header */
#define MAX_RESPONDENTS 6
#define MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE -20                                                 /* Abbreviated MiRV */
#define MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE 5                                                   /* Abbreviated MaRV */
#define RESPONSE_VALUE 26                                                      /* Equals |(MiRV)| + |(MaRV)| + 1 */
#define STOP 3
#define BREAK 1

int main(void)
{
    CountRating();

    return 0;
}

void CountRating()
{
    int ratingCounters, rating[RESPONSE_VALUE] = {0}, Response, response;

    for (ratingCounters = 0; ratingCounters < MAX_RESPONDENTS;)
    {
        int response, stop = STOP;
        printf("Enter a integer rating between %d and %d for the product: ", MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE, MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE);
        scanf("%d", &response);

        if (response <= MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE && response >= MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE)
            stop = STOP, Response = response;
        else
        {
            int stopElse = stop;
            if (stopElse < BREAK)
                break;
            else
            {
                do
                {
                    printf("\nNot within range. Try again.\nYou have %d more attempts before program outputs total:", stop);
                    scanf("%d", &response);
                    printf("\n");
                    --stop;
                    if (stop < BREAK)
                    break;
                } while (response > MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE || response < MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE);
            }   if (stop < BREAK)
                break;
        }
        ++rating[Response];
        ++ratingCounters;

    }
    printf("\nRating            Number of Responses\n");
    printf("------            -------------------");
    for (ratingCounters = MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE; ratingCounters >= MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE; --ratingCounters)
    {

        printf("\n%3d %23d", rating[RESPONSE_VALUE], rating[Response]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it? Your indexes are totally off! Look at how you use the "`Response`".

Comment: tried debugging, it didn't work though.

Comment: then print your variables at every state. You'll see the problem right away. And learn how to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array indexes start at 0, yet your response numbers range from -20 to +5 (26 values).  So, when you write:

```
++rating[Response];
```

you are not accessing the array element you should be accessing.  You need to do something like subtract the MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE from the entered value.

Your output loop is printing the same response every time because you're accessing the same array element every time:

```
for (ratingCounters = MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE; ratingCounters >= MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE; --ratingCounters)
{
    printf("\n%3d %23d", rating[RESPONSE_VALUE], rating[Response]);
}
```

There are reasons why loop indexes and array indexes are given names like `i`; this code is an examplar.  It makes the code hard to read.  You should be indexing by some value calculated from `ratingCounters`.  One of the values should be `ratingCounters`; the other an array element bassed on a value calculated from `ratingCounters`.

Comment: that's not the only problem in that code. Some questions are not meant to be answered, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Start by what you know, the printouts are not expected. Verify that your code does what you expect. What are the values of `RESPONSE_VALUE` and `Response`?

Comment: Response is a variable. RESPONSE_VALUE = |MIN| + |MAX| + 1